# magmi Image processor remote import issue

Tags: magmi

magmi image processor imports remote images, even if they don't exist!

In the following example, image-03.jpg does not exist on the remote server. But the image processor, creates a blank record under Product Information > Images. It imports image.jpg, image-01.jpg, image-02.jpg and creates (assigns) a 4th blank record.

I don't think it makes any difference, but I am using Bundle Item processor v1.1 as well.

csv file record sample:
image,small_image,thumbnail,media_gallery
+http://domainDOTcom/images/image.jpg,http://domainDOTcom/images/image.jpg,http://domainDOTcom/images/image.jpg,http://domainDOTcom/images/image-01.jpg;http://domainDOTcom/images/image-02.jpg;http://domainDOTcom/images/image-03.jpg

Comment: Did you find a solution about this mate?